# Get image clicked in CarouselView

Tags: c#, forms, image, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a CarouselView with multiple images and I want to get what have been clicked or tapped. I have tried adding a x:Name but I can't access to this property in a GestureRecognizer.

This is my xaml. I have 4 pages with 2 pictures in each one. I would get the x:Name of the image clicked or something that I can know where image has been clicked.

```
<Image Grid.Row="0" Aspect="Fill" Source="{Binding Image1}" x:Name="{Binding ImageName1}" >
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                  <TapGestureRecognizer
                          Tapped="ClickImage" />
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
          </Image>
<Image Grid.Row="1" Aspect="Fill" Source="{Binding Image2}" x:Name="{Binding ImageName2}">
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
              <TapGestureRecognizer
                      Tapped="ClickImage" />
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
          </Image>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and see if it works:

Add a classid to the image in xaml:

```
 ClassId ="{Binding Image2}"
```

And use it like this. imageString contains the unique image.

```
 async void ClickImage(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
 {
    Image image = (Image)sender;
    string imageString = image.ClassId;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(imageString);

 }
```

Comment: Thank you!! It's just what I was looking for!

Comment: No problem! :) Glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to set a different tapped gesture handler for each image such as

```
<Image Grid.Row="0" Aspect="Fill" Source="{Binding Image1}" x:Name="{Binding ImageName1}" >
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                  <TapGestureRecognizer
                          Tapped="ClickImage1" />
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
          </Image>
<Image Grid.Row="1" Aspect="Fill" Source="{Binding Image2}" x:Name="{Binding ImageName2}">
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
              <TapGestureRecognizer
                      Tapped="ClickImage2" />
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
          </Image>
```